Uniform Convergence and ODE
The following problem appeared on a past exam at my institution:
Suppose that for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $u_n:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a differentiable function satisfying $$u_n'(x)=F(u_n(x),x)$$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ where $F:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a continuous bounded function.
(i) If $u:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a function such that $u_n\rightarrow u$ uniformly as $n\rightarrow\infty$, prove that $u$ is differentiable with $$u'(x)=F(u(x),x)$$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.
(ii) If $x_0,y_0\in\mathbb{R}$ and $u:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is the unique function satisfying $$u'(x)=F(u(x),x), u(x_0)=y_0$$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and if $u_n(x_0)\rightarrow y_0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$, prove that $u_n\rightarrow u$ uniformly as $n\rightarrow\infty$.
To prove (i), I've already tried showing that $u_n'\rightarrow g$ uniformly as $n\rightarrow\infty$ where $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is given by $g(x):=F(u(x),x)$ but to no avail. To prove (ii), I recognize that it suffices to show that $(u_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges uniformly to some function $\tilde{u}:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ because (i) then implies $\tilde{u}=u$. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Note that the $u_n$ are uniformly Lipschitz.

I believe I have worked out part (i). Here is my proof:
Fix $x_0\in\mathbb{R}$ and suppose $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Given $\epsilon\in(0,\infty)$, there exists $N_1\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ such that $$||u_n-u||<\frac{\epsilon}{3}$$ whenever $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+\cap[N_1,\infty)$. Since $[\mathrm{min}(x,x_0),\mathrm{max}(x,x_0)]\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ is compact and $u$ is continuous, there exists $M\in(0,\infty)$ such that $|u(t)|\leq M$ for all $t\in[\mathrm{min}(x,x_0),\mathrm{max}(x,x_0)]$. Next, there exists $N_2\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ such that $$||u_n-u||<1$$ whenever $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+\cap[N_2,\infty)$. Since $[-(M+1),M+1]\times[\mathrm{min}(x,x_0),\mathrm{max}(x,x_0)]\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$ is compact and $F$ is continuous, there exists $\delta\in(0,\infty)$ such that $$|F(s_1,t_1)-F(s_2,t_2)|<\frac{\epsilon}{3|x-x_0|+1}$$ whenever $(s_1,t_1),(s_2,t_2)\in[-(M+1),M+1]\times[\mathrm{min}(x,x_0),\mathrm{max}(x,x_0)]$ satisfy $||(s_1,t_1)-(s_2,t_2)||<\delta$, so there exists $N_3\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ such that $$||u_n-u||<\delta$$ whenever $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+\cap[N_3,\infty)$. Finally, set $$N:=\mathrm{max}(N_1,N_2,N_3)$$ and observe that $$|u(x)-(u(x_0)+\int^x_{x_0}F(u(t),t)dt)|=$$$$|u(x)-u_N(x)-(u(x_0)-(u_N(x_0))-\int^x_{x_0}(F(u(t),t)-F(u_N(t),t))dt|\leq$$$$|u(x)-u_N(x)|+|u(x_0)-u_N(x_0)|+\int^{\mathrm{max}(x,x_0)}_{\mathrm{min}(x,x_0)}|F(u(t),t)-F(u_N(t),t)|dt<$$$$\frac{\epsilon}{3}+\frac{\epsilon}{3}+\int^{\mathrm{max}(x,x_0)}_{\mathrm{min}(x,x_0)}\frac{\epsilon}{3|x-x_0|+1}dt=\frac{2\epsilon}{3}+\frac{\epsilon\cdot|x-x_0|}{3|x-x_0|+1}<\epsilon$$ proving $$u(x)=u(x_0)+\int^x_{x_0}F(u(t),t)dt$$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. By the fundamental theorem of calculus, $$u'(x)=F(u(x),x)$$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.
